# aggregate with dynamic field path- mongo DB and nodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, dynamic, field, aggregation

I have a collection- 'products' that contains the following documents:

```
{
  productName: "computer",
  updateAt: "2022-07-12T12:44:47.485Z",
  createAt: ""2022-06-12T10:34:03.485Z",
  changeAt: ""2022-09-12T10:39:40.485Z"
}
```

I want to create an aggregation that convert the field "updateAt" from string to date.

for this, I created this aggregation:

```
db.products.aggregate([{
        $set: {
          updateAt: {
            $dateFromString: {
              dateString: '$updateAt'
            }
          }
        },
      },
      {
        $out: 'products'
      }]
    )
```

It works fine for this need, but as you can see I specified the field path "updateAt" in a hard coded way.I want to use the above aggregation in a dynamic way-
considering I have an array of fields that I want to change:

```
const fields = ['updateAt', 'createAt', 'changeAt']
```

I want to loop over the fields array and use each field as a fieldPath so I can transfer the field name to the aggregation, something like that-

```
fields.forEech(field -> {
  db.products.aggregate([{
        $set: {
          `${field}`: {
            $dateFromString: {
              dateString: `$${field}`
            }
          }
        },
      },
      {
        $out: 'products'
      }]
    )
}

As you can understand it's not working for me....
How can I achieve my goal?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some errors in your `nodejs` function, also, `aggregate` method returns a `Promise`, so you will need to wait for it, to resolve before moving further.

Try this:

```
const fields = ['updateAt', 'createAt', 'changeAt']
for(let i=0; i < fields.length; i++) {
  let field = fields[i];
  await db.products.aggregate([{
        "$set": {
          [field]: {
            "$dateFromString": {
              "dateString": `$${field}`
            }
          }
        },
      },
      {
        "$out": 'products'
      }]
    )
}
```

Also, make the function containing this piece of code `async`.

Comment: Hi, thanks! 
The syntax- [field] is exactly what I needed...

Interesting why I didn't find it on google... (searched to know how to pass field path as variable and not hard coded)

Have a great day, and thanks again!